# Como insertar datos en arrays desde un archivo .txt c++

Tags: c++

Quisiera saber si es posible, y de serlo, como insertar los datos de un archivo `.txt` con 3 columnas a su arreglo correspondiente, por ejemplo quiero guardar los datos de la columna 1 en el arreglo 1, los datos de la columna 2 en el arreglo 2 y los datos de la columna 3 en el arreglo 3, si me pueden dar alguna pista se los agradecería mucho.

Un ejemplo de cómo están estructurados los datos en el archivo `.txt` para los arreglos al inicio del código.

Agradecería si me pueden ayudar con algunos consejos o pistas, gracias

```
 /*
Array 1  Array 2  Array 3
7441781 7860172 -7325677
-3991040 2767400 -5089157
9266561 9256845 -8274370
*/  

#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;


int numeros1[]={12,12,12}; //aqui deberian ir los numeros del txt en la primera columna
int numeros2[]={12,12,12}; //aqui deberian ir los numeros del txt en la segunda columna
int numeros3[]={12,12,12}; //aqui deberian ir los numeros del txt en la tercera columna
int num1,num2;
string texto;

void lectura();

int main(){
    lectura();

    return 0;
}
void lectura(){
    ifstream archivo;

    archivo.open("Arreglo1.txt",ios::in);  //abriendo archivo donde se encuentran los datos

    if(archivo.fail()){

        cout<<"no se pudo abrir el archivo";
        exit(1);
    }

    while(!archivo.eof()){
        getline(archivo,texto);    //añadiendo los datos del documento a una variable llamada texto
        cout<<texto<<endl;
    }
    archivo.close();


}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Si tu archivo va a tener siempre la misma estructura, puedes leer los datos secuencialmente:

```
std::vector<int> numeros1, numeros2, numeros3;

for (std::ifstream o{"Arreglo1.txt"}; o;)
{
    int numero;

    if (o >> numero)
        numeros1.push_back(numero);
    if (o >> numero)
        numeros2.push_back(numero);
    if (o >> numero)
        numeros3.push_back(numero);
}
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/hl4ltyl5QqeCXvUK)</kbd>.